# Native code for javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, native

I have been trying to find some version of the native code (C/C++) for javascript arrays to see how their methods are implemented, but I have been having trouble sifting through the vast number of files. I have looked through the v8 engine open source (https://github.com/v8/v8/tree/master/src) and the mozilla open source (https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/). I'm sure these sources have a strong structure to them, but I can seem to break it and find what I'm looking for.

Does anyone have a link/tutorial/advice on how to find the native code for arrays? And, more generally, a link/tutorial/advice on how to maneuver through one of the javascript native code databases?

Edit: Maybe I'm assuming that the source code is too simplistic, but I think I'm looking for something that looks something like this: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Arrays.java.html, but in C/C++ for javascript

Comment: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-array.cc maybe?

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the JS engine implementation, or are you just interested in using equivalent functionality in your native program?

Comment: I'm looking for the implementation.

Comment: …and the rest can be found in https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js

Comment: @Bergi: So these methods are written in JS? That's crazy! I was sure that I was looking for them in C/C++. Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: Also, thanks @FelixKling

Comment: @Saralyn some of them, yes. They use some native primitives (that aren't otherwise available - everything prefixed with `%`) and are written in a way that they will get nicely optimised by the compiler.